# assert in static block Eclipse-java

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, runtime-error, assert

I was studying assert, so wrote the following code

```
public class AssertionDemo
{
    static
    {
        int i=7;
        assert i>10:i;
    }
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     int i=8;
     assert (i<10):8;
     assert (i>10):9;
 }
}
```

Before Console Output, i get the following dialog box

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 7
at logicBuliding.AssertionDemo.<clinit>(AssertionDemo.java:8)
```

What is up with the dialog box?

Comment: What do you expect instead of this dialog box. An exception occurred, and javaw.exe tells you about it. Would you prefer if it silently failed?

Comment: I do not get the question. There is an Exception, so it is ok to show the dialog-box.

Comment: The third line of your code snippet seems rather...strange. `static` *what*, exactly?

Comment: @JackManey i am trying to see how assert acts in various situation, especially if we initialize values using static block, before the program execution.how will assert work up.

Comment: To Jack maney: That is static initialization code. It is run the first time the class is loaded before any method is called for that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this isn't specifically about assertions - it's just about a failure to even get to the `main` method when starting an application. In most cases that would indicate a pretty serious error, and the launcher code may not have much information easily to hand about exactly how far it got. Showing a dialog box is probably safer than relying on the console already being hooked up (given that we're definitely in a bad situation).

Here's a slightly simpler program which behaves the same way:

```
public class Test {
    static {
        if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bang!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }    
}
```

You don't need Eclipse to demonstrate this - just using `javaw` will give the same effect, [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). Running with `java` from a command line just shows the exception though, for me:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bang!
        at Test.<clinit>(Test.java:4)
```

Comment: Yup. `javaw` does this, and it is described here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: @iccthedral: Cracking, thanks - will edit that into the answer.